# Swift selector - unrecognized selector sent to instance (UIDatePicker)

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I have problem with trying to get UIDatePicker to work when the user select a date.
I keep getting an error saying : unrecognised selector sent to instance.

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    textField.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("datePickerChanged:")), for: .valueChanged)

}




func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    DEPtextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

Comment: Please try by removing one extra parenthesis. Use only Selector("datePickerChanged:")

Comment: Please provide the code with a minimal example in your post, not just by a link.

Comment: if you are using Swift 2.2, you have to use #selector...

Comment: I have try to removing extra parenthesis, it will shown "no method declared with Object-C Selector" and I'm using the latest version not swift2.2 @spaleja

Comment: I've edit my questions, could u help @mario

Comment: Could you solve it. Have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker has own property to response change event.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents/1618238-valuechanged

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as follows

```
func datePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    DEPtextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

It should work.